# Ain't - what does it mean?

Tags: aint

First of all, thx for this site. It's great for me. I read it everyday, because I want to grow up my english skills. I'm from Poland btw. :)

My question is this:

**What does it mean 'ain't'?** I don't understand this language-tool. Could U explain it to me? I will be very greatfull! :)

Answer (score 3):

"**ain't**" is an informal contraction of "am not; are not; is not", or "has not; have not." 
For example: "*if it ain't broke, don't fix it*" → If it is not broken, do not fix it. 
"*they ain't got nothing to say*"  → They have nothing to say.

Comment: Thx U very much! Now I understand! :)

Comment: Surely the second example is a poor choice without special disclaimers. It reads as "ain't got" = "have", or, by the rules, should translate to "they have not got nothing to say", and then there's the double-negative.

Comment: @Avon: By *any* rules, "X ain't got nothing to say" is a double negative - same as [I can't get no satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(I_Can't_Get_No)_Satisfaction) and [We don't need no education](http://genius.com/1488557) But these are perfectly natural and common usages, so since this isn't [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), I see no reason to include any kind of "disclaimer" here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ok... and on the fact that the translation doesn't follow the given rules? In short, I disagree a little bit. I think it's a misleading example.

Comment: Sorry, I apologise for my mistake! I only noticed it after posting my message, you're right Avon. As for the disclaimers, as the sentences indeed appeared of "common usage", I deemed them unnecessary.